# Hostel booking date

Tags: usa, hotels, california

[image]

I arrive in San Francisco at 10.30 pm. Should I book a hostel on that night itself or the day after which is 12 am onwards?

I'm pretty confused because when I proceed to the payment page, one of the column stated the arrival time as 23:00 (11 pm). What if I can only check in after 11 pm? Given that my arrival time at the airport is already 10:30 pm, that's not including any delays, claiming baggage, requesting an Uber etc.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share a screenshot of the mentioned booking page.

Comment: Are you worried that you won't be able to check in after 23:00?

Comment: Hi Newton, I just uploaded the screenshot.

Comment: Hi Neusser! Yes, that's what I'm worried about. There isn't any other time option to pick, I mean right after 12am onwards, check in midnight.

Comment: Are you sure the hostel allows for check-in after 11pm? Some places actually do close their reception at night...

Answer (score 3):

Same-day booking. If you book for the next day, you won't be able [most probably] to get a room until lunch time, which would be quite inconvenient. If you're worried that the room will be given to someone else because you're late, (1) inform the hotel, and (2) prepay the room.

Comment: Hi dda! Alright and duly noted. I understood now. Thank you very much.